Overlay Stretches in Mobile view
I want to make the overlay stretch to cover all the content in mobile view such as 4 rows with 2 cells per row total 7 cells.last row have only one cell.
This is the code that i have written and it' fine on desktop view ..My requirement is elaborated on above on mobile view .enter image description here

When i paste my code it shows too long

Pls provide a reproducible snippet of your problem for a better help

For small screens (like on mobile phones), you want to show the content in 4 rows with 2 boxes in each row. The last row will have only 1 box that stretches across the full width.
To make this happen, you need to change the layout styles based on the screen size. On small screens, instead of showing the boxes side-by-side, you want them to stack on top of each other, with 2 boxes per row, except for the last row which will have just 1 wide box.
For more Please share your codes.
